# c# scrolling using mousewheel without scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, scrollbar

I'm trying to dynamically change the view of a panel that contains buttons in my winforms application using the mousewheel. I'm basically changing the location of the panel using the code below however whenever I use the mousewheel to scroll, the scrollbars can be seen. They sort of flask/ flicker into view when I change the location. Is there any way to stop the scrollbars from appearing?

```
location -= 40;
this.pnl.VerticalScroll.Value = location;
this.pnl.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, location);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simple change it from winforms, since it is being automatically displayed by windows. There is a not so great solution for this issue.I had a similar requirement and what I used was this :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool ShowScrollBar(IntPtr hWnd, int wBar, bool bShow);

private enum ScrollBarDirection
{
    SB_HORZ = 0,
    SB_VERT = 1,
    SB_CTL = 2,
    SB_BOTH = 3
}

protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    ShowScrollBar(panel1.Handle, (int)ScrollBarDirection.SB_VERT, false);
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

1. Import the win32 dll `user32.dll`
2. Call the ShowScrollBar method in it with required parameters as shown in above example

Comment: How do you import user32.dll?

Comment: The scrollbar still flashes. Doesn't look like the code is doing anything.